# Change colors of select lines in ggplot2 coefficient plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, coefplot

I would like to change the color of coefficient lines based on whether the point estimate is negative or positive in a ggplot2 coefficient plot in R. For example:

```
require(coefplot)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))
mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x + z, data = dat)
coefplot.lm(mod1)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

In this plot, I would like to change the "x" variable to red when plotted. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Were does `coefplot.lm` come from? Not from `base` or `ggplot2` i think?!

Comment: coefplot is a package by Jared P. Lander

Comment: Apologies, now edited with the package.

Comment: In ggplot I would create a factor with two levels for the negative and positive values. Then add that to my aes with `group=thatfactor, color=thatfacor`. I am not familiar with coefplot, isn't there a similair option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you cannot do this with a plot produced by `coefplot.lm`. The package `coefplot` uses `ggplot2` as the plotting system, which is good itself, but does not allow to play with colors as easily as you would like. To achieve the desired colors, you need to have a variable in your dataset that would color-code the values; you need to specify `color = color-code` in `aes()` function within the layer that draws the dots with CE. Apparently, this is impossible to do with the output of `coefplot.lm` function. Maybe, you can change the colors using `ggplot2` `ggplot_build()` function. I would say, it's easier to write your own function for this task.

---

I've done this once to plot odds. If you want, you may use my code. Feel free to change it. The idea is the same as in `coefplot`. First, we extract coefficients from a model object and prepare the data set for plotting; second, actually plot.

---

#### The code for extracting coefficients and data set preparation

```
df_plot_odds <- function(x){
tmp<-data.frame(cbind(exp(coef(x)), exp(confint.default(x))))
odds<-tmp[-1,]
names(odds)<-c('OR', 'lower', 'upper')
odds$vars<-row.names(odds)
odds$col<-odds$OR>1
odds$col[odds$col==TRUE] <-'blue'
odds$col[odds$col==FALSE] <-'red'
odds$pvalue <- summary(x)$coef[-1, "Pr(>|t|)"]
return(odds)
}
```

#### Plot the output of the extract function

```
plot_odds <- function(df_plot_odds, xlab="Odds Ratio", ylab="", asp=1){
    require(ggplot2)
    p <- ggplot(df_plot_odds, aes(x=vars, y=OR, ymin=lower, ymax=upper),asp=asp) + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(color=col),width=0.1) + 
        geom_point(aes(color=col),size=3)+
        geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype=2) +
        scale_color_manual('Effect', labels=c('Positive','Negative'),
                          values=c('blue','red'))+   
        coord_flip() +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position="none",aspect.ratio = asp)+
        ylab(xlab) +
        xlab(ylab) #switch because of the coord_flip() above
    return(p)
}
```

---

#### Plotting your example

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),y = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))
mod1 <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = dat)
df <- df_plot_odds(mod1)
plot <- plot_odds(df)
plot
```

Which yields

[image]

Note that I chose `theme_wb()` as the default. Output is a `ggplot2`object. So, you may change it quite a lot.